# loop variable aware numpy's slicing and vectorized calculations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I speedup following pure python code using numpy's slicing and vectorized (automatic looping) calculations

```
def foo(x, i, j):
  return x + i + j % 255

h, w = img.shape[:2]   # img is a numpy array of shape (100,100,1)
out_img = img.copy()
for i in xrange(h):
  for j in xrange(w):
    out_img[i][j] = foo(img[i][j], i, j)
```

If foo is of the form 'foo(img[i][j])' (without loop variable as params), following works for me

```
out_img[0:,0:] = foo(img[0:,0:])
```

Note : Numpy gives ~70x speedup for above case compared to pure python.

I am not able to figure how to to get it working for function foo with loop variables as params.
Can someone help?

Comment: This is not possible without additional knowledge of how `foo` works.

Comment: foo is a simple function say lambda x, i, j: x + i + j % 255. I have edited the question to include definition of foo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [`numpy.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html), like:

```
out_img = foo(img, *np.indices(shape=(h,w)))
```

Or slightly more explicit:

```
h_indices, w_indices = np.indices(shape=(h,w))
out_img = foo(img, h_indices, w_indices)
```

To illustrate what `np.indices` does:

```
np.indices((3,2))
=> 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

Comment: `img[:,:]` could just as easily be `img` here, right? Since for this particular `foo` no entry of `img` is being overwritten, and so no copy needs to be made.

Comment: @jme: And in any case, `img[:,:]` will share `img`'s buffer rather than making a copy.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, very true, that's what I meant to say. I even went so far as to open a terminal, test that they shared memory, and still said the opposite!